# Error on 2nd run of for-loop - TypeError: cannot find function getrange in object

Tags: google-apps-script

This script runs against a sample sheet with 3 sample rows. It runs correctly through the first loop. Then, on the 2nd loop, it throws

> cannot find function getrange in object

on this line

```
value1.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+8+":B"+8), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Code:

```
function MassEmail() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //var range = ss.getActiveRange();
    var inputs = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var temp = ss.getSheets()[1]; 
    var team = ss.getSheets()[2];
    var fees = ss.getSheets()[3];
    var display = ss.getSheets()[4];
    var pdf = ss.getSheets()[5];

    //CHANGE temp to inputs IF YOU NEED TO SEND EMAIL CONTRACT TO ALL CONTACTS
    var row = inputs.getLastRow();
    var dataRange = inputs.getRange(2, 2, row, 5); // Fetch values for each row in the Range
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var school = data[i];
    if (school[1] != "" && school[2] != "OK") {
    // Browser.msgBox(data[i]);

    var process1 = temp.getRange(2,1,1,5)
    process1.setValues([school]);
    var process2 = temp.getRange("A"+2+":D"+4);
    process2.copyTo(temp.getRange("A"+2+":D"+4), {contentsOnly:true});

    var value1 = display.getRange("B"+8+":B"+8);
    value1.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+8+":B"+8), {contentsOnly:true});
    var value2 = display.getRange("B"+9+":B"+9);
    value2.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+9+":B"+9), {contentsOnly:true}); 
    var value3 = display.getRange("B"+22);
    value3.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+22), {contentsOnly:true});
    var value4 = display.getRange("B"+24);
    value4.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+24), {contentsOnly:true});
    var value5 = display.getRange("B"+31);
    value5.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+31), {contentsOnly:true});
    //var range = pdf.getRange("B"+31);
    //range.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"));
    var value6 = display.getRange("B"+34);
    value6.copyTo(pdf.getRange("B"+34), {contentsOnly:true});

    // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(" snapshot");
    sheet = pdf;
    pdf.copyTo(newSpreadsheet); 

    // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
    newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
    newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

    // Make PDF
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var attach = {fileName:'2016 file.pdf', content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

    var emailSubject = "subject"
    var emailYourName = "person 
    var emailReply = "email@cox.net"

    var emailMsg = ""


    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    MailApp.sendEmail(school[1], emailSubject, emailMsg,{htmlbody: emailMsg, name: emailYourName, replyTo: emailReply, bcc:"person@gmail.com", attachments:[attach]});

    // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
    DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true); 

    inputs.getRange(i+2,6).setValue("OK"); 
    //temp.getRange(i+2,5).setValue("OK");

    // clear row 2 in temp sheet
    temp.getRange(2, 1, 2, 5).clear({contentsOnly:true});

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is declaring the variable `pdf` twice for two different data types.

```
var pdf = ss.getSheets()[5];
```

And

```
// Make PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId())
            .getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
```

Rename one of them.  Maybe change `pdf` to `pdf_File`:

```
var pdf_File = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId())
            .getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
```

Comment: Sandy, Thank you so much!  That was so simple but the error was "non descript" and since my last change to the code was made due to issues with making the PDF attachments, I should have looked there, but it continued to escape me! You are a gem!   Thank you for finding & responding!!

Comment: You have now been released from coding jail.  I think of it as prisoner release.